# laravel - redirecting three different user types/roles to different pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I use laravel 5.4 and I want to redirect these three different types of users to different pages

#### Schema

---

```
Types
+-------+-------------+
| id    | name        |
+-------+-------------+
| 1     | Super Admin |
| 2     | Admin       |
| 3     | Cashier     |
+-------+-------------+

Users    
+-------+---------+-------------+
| id    | type_id | name        |
+-------+---------+-------------+
| 1     | 1       | Super Admin |
| 2     | 2       | Admin       |
| 3     | 3       | Cashier     |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

i write code like this

```
use Auth;

public function redirectTo()
{
    $superAdmin = Auth::user()->type_id = 1;
    $admin = Auth::user()->type_id = 2;
    $cashier = Auth::user()->type_id = 3;

    if ($superAdmin) {
        return '/superAdmin/home';
    }
    elseif ($admin) {
        return '/admin/home';
    }
    elseif ($cashier) {
        return '/cashier/home';
    }
}
```

but it always redirects to '/superAdmin/home', can someone tell what my fault is?

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand what you have written in your code 
You are assigning 1 to $supseadmin as well as 
auth::User()->type_id

Then in the if condition you are checking
 if($superadmin){}

means if(1){} 
Then this type of if condition just check if the data exists then it goes in to the if statements body where you are returning
To super admin

Answer (score 0):

```
use Auth;

public function redirectTo()
{
    $superAdmin = 1;
    $admin  = 2;
    $cashier = 3;

    if ($superAdmin == Auth::user()->type_id) {
        return '/superAdmin/home';
    }
    elseif ($admin == Auth::user()->type_id) {
        return '/admin/home';
    }
    elseif ($cashier == Auth::user()->type_id) {
        return '/cashier/home';
    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: I think your suggestion is the same as the suggestion I tried from others, but my problem is still the same as before as I have explained here [fails to redirect multiple authentication to different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925466/laravel-fails-to-redirect-multiple-authentication-to-different-pages) could you help me?

Comment: I think you are getting role type 1 for every user. Put die in redirect redirect_to method before if loop and check what user role type you are getting for every user

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `type_id` with some value, for example:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    if (auth()->user()->type_id === 1) {
        return '/superAdmin/home';
    } elseif (auth()->user()->type_id === 2) {
        return '/admin/home';
    } elseif (auth()->user()->type_id === 3) {
        return '/cashier/home';
    }
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to [use constants instead of integers](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#use-config-and-language-files-constants-instead-of-text-in-the-code) like 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions, but my problem is still the same as before as I explained here [fails to redirect multiple authentication to different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925466/laravel-fails-to-redirect-multiple-authentication-to-different-pages) could you help me?