# laravel - fails to redirect multiple authentication to different pages

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I use laravel 5.4 and I want to redirect these three different types of users to different pages

**Schema**

```
Types
+-------+-------------+
| id    | name        |
+-------+-------------+
| 1     | Super Admin |
| 2     | Admin       |
| 3     | Cashier     |
+-------+-------------+

Users    
+-------+---------+-------------+
| id    | type_id | name        |
+-------+---------+-------------+
| 1     | 1       | Super Admin |
| 2     | 2       | Admin       |
| 3     | 3       | Cashier     |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

**LoginController**

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    if (Auth::user()->type_id === 1) {
        return '/superAdmin/home';
    }
    elseif (Auth::user()->type_id === 2) {
        return '/admin/home';
    }
    elseif (Auth::user()->type_id === 3) {
        return '/kasir/home';
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public function superAdmin()
{
    return view('superAdmin.home');
}

public function admin()
{
    return view('admin.home');
}

public function kasir()
{
    return view('kasir.home');
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@kasir');
Route::get('/admin/home', 'HomeController@admin');
Route::get('/superAdmin/home', 'HomeController@superAdmin');
```

I followed the answer of my previous question

[redirecting three different user types/roles to different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909378/laravel-redirecting-three-different-user-types-roles-to-different-pages/47911667#47911667)

I tried to sign in using a user with type_id = 1, which means the user is a super admin, but it always redirects to `Route::get('/','HomeController@cashier');` as well as users with other roles

and the problem is that each role can access the page belongs to another role, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: try with only `==` instead `===` in your login controller

Comment: @HirenMangukiya I have tried it and it is still the same as before

Comment: Did you checked you got correct value from `Auth::user()->type_id`

Comment: @HirenMangukiya sure, i have checked it

Comment: try storing url to variable and return the variable.`if(Auth::user()->type_id === 1) {
        $variable = "/admin/home";
    } return $variable;`

Comment: @ab_in still the same as before

Comment: Dump your `Auth::user()->type_id` and show the result here. Also try commenting redirectTo property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing which i had been use in my last project using laravel.

You have to write this code in home controller's index method so while load home-page it going to check user type id and redirect to appropriate page.

```
 if(Auth::check()) {
        if(Auth::user()->in_usertype_id == 1) {
              return view('admin.dashboard');
        }elseif(Auth::user()->in_usertype_id == 2) {
              return view('admin.dashboard1');
       else{
             return view('admin.dashboard3');
       }
 }else{
             return redirect('login')->with('error', 
             Lang::get('message.unauthorize-access'));
}
```

Hope this will helps you.